# nHibernate returns double the number of records

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

My query is returning exactly double amount of rows I expect. When I look at nHibernate profiler, I see the query I expect, but it appears twice in the profiler...

Mappings:

A Location has many LocationRooms which has many LocationRoomLayouts:

**Location**

```
 public LocationMap()
 {
    Id(x => x.locationID).Column("ID");

    HasMany(x => x.LocationRooms)
       .KeyColumn("LID") 
       .Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All();
 }
```

**Location Room**

```
 public LocationRoomMap ()
 {
      References(x => x.Location).Column("LID");
      HasMany(x => x.LocationRoomLayouts)
          .KeyColumn("RID")
          .Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All();
 }
```

**Location Room layout**

```
 public LocationRoomLayoutMap()
 {
       References(x => x.LocationRoom).Column("RID");
 }
```

**the query that is returning double the rows:**

```
 var locations = session.CreateCriteria<LocationRoomLayout>("p")
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CostPerHour", 0))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CostPerDay", 0))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CostPerHalfDay", 0))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CostPerPerson", 0))
                         .List<LocationRoomLayout>();
```

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate uses the resultset that it has retrieved from the database to build the entities.
Since your entities consist of data that is coming from different tables, the database returns multiple times the same record from your 'master' table.

Therefore, multiple entities are returned.
Use the DistinctRootEntityTransformer to make sure that NHibernate only returns distinct entities.

More information can be found [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/get-unique-results-from-joined-queries.aspx)

Comment: I've tried adding .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()) and I get the exact same result... I believe this is a different problem, since the SQL generated in nHibernateProfiler is perfect, it's just exectured twice